# SQL Server Property - Cluster Node Computer Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Veritas clustered environment and I am trying to use SQL to pull in the active node's computer name.  I have used the following link: http://www.erichumphrey.com/2011/04/serverproperty/ to list all of the server's properties.  However, the `ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS`, `MachineName`, and `ServerName` all refer to the SQL Server instance name, not the actual computer name.  In this case, the SQL instances are named.

Also, `select @@servername` does not show the computer name.

I am looking for the "Computer Name", if I right click on "My Computer" and choose "Properties".
[image]

Comment: Is it a default instance (OR) named instance?

Comment: For this example, there are 4 named instances on this server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it by using the following code:

```
declare @dir varchar(4000) 

exec master.dbo.xp_regread 
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName','ComputerName',
    @dir output
select @dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Check what's the value of the registry property `ComputerName` under the registry path. the same will be displayed by `SERVERPROPERTY` as well.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_Machine\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\
```

Comment: The name that appears in HKEY_LOCAL_Machine\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\ is correct, but I do not see that name listed in any of the server properties.

Comment: Am not sure but `ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS` actually supposed to give you the node name where instance is running in a clustered environment.